# Save assembly to disk with C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I would like to save one of the currently imported assemblies to local disk inside a C++ program. Is it possible to save the assembly if I know the name of it?

```
//access the assembly by name
HMODULE hAssem = GetModuleHandleA( "name.dll" );

//now somehow save to disk
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `AssemblyBuilder::Save()` to save a dynamic assembly to disk

Check out [code example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zwdfdeh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1).